# What's the advantage of case sensitive languages over case insensitive ones?

Tags: programming-languages, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have been doing a number of projects in Delphi, which uses the case insensitive language Pascal, and I was wondering what the advantage of case sensitive languages is.
Jason [argues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309300/defend-php-convince-me-it-isnt-horrible) that "Case insensitivity introduces much ambiguity". I don't agree. If you realize that the language is case insensitive you know that `WHILE` means the same thing as `while`, even if you never write the former. Same for variables and functions; camel casing is nice, but was the first letter also a capital or not? And what about functions whose name starts with an underscore? In case insensitive languages no problem: `_fooBar` will do just as nicely as `_FooBar`. So where's the ambiguity Jason refers to? Yes, you can write a variable in different ways, but the meaning is unambiguous! `FooBar` == `foobar`!

In the same thread Delnan [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309300/defend-php-convince-me-it-isnt-horrible/3900114#3900114) that `Capitalization is the difference between "I had to help my uncle Jack off a horse.." and "I had to help my uncle jack off a horse.."`. Very clever :-). But rather a point against than pro case sensitivity: would you accept that your code goes haywire because of a single capitalization error? Again, in a case insensitive language, if `Jack` is a person, so is `jack`.

**Question**: is there anyone who uses this feature in case sensitive languages that you can define two different variables or functions just by different capitalization? Because that's the only advantage I can see in it. Sure, you'll say, I write the variable name with camel casing and the constant all uppercase. But IMO they're incompatible; `userName` as a variable makes sense, but `USERNAME` as a constant doesn't.

(I realize that many programmers use case sensitive languages, so I'm prepared for a unwelcome reception :-))

**edit**
The trigger for this question was Lynda.com's "ActionScript 3.0 in Flash CS3 Professional" training video, in which Todd Perkins spends half of his time emphasizing the capitalizations :-)

Comment: I think you should ask this on http://Programmers.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I think you should **not** ask this on Programmers.SE, because it was already [asked](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/9965) there.

Comment: @Pavel, isn't the fact that it was asked there (and not closed) a good sign that it *is* in fact the correct venue?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I *absolutely* use this all the time in C#:

```
private readonly string name;
public string Name { get { return name; } }
```

I've tended to use case-sensitive languages, and haven't really seen downsides of them - aside from anything else, they *force* consistency of casing.

It's really a personal preference thing though, I think.

Comment: I've worked with case-sensitive languages all my career, and I sometimes wish C# wasn't! Oh well, that's never going to happen!

Comment: More of a mindset thing than a preference thing I reckon. When I first came to C# from Delphi I was horrified by this coding style. Now I use it all the time and I'm fine with it. I'm fine with case-insensitive Delphi too.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like neat and tidy code. If your language is not case sensitive it has the potential to be come messy if everyone doesn't stick to the rules.

```
private String myName = "Shawn";

  if(myname.equals("Shawn"){
    MYNAME = myname + "Vader";
  }

  System.out.println("His name is " + MyName);
```

Even in a case sensitive language we spend a lot of time making sure that everything is consistent, like running analysis tools to enforce naming conventions of fields and formatting rules and final method parameters.

So for me it's a question of conformity.